# code is not loading all the data set and training the model on it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

hello i am learning to use Tensorflow for machine learning and deep learning, i am following along a video for [freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ), and this is the video i am watching [TensorFlow 2.0 Complete Course - Python Neural Networks for Beginners Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPYj3fFJGjk&list=PLGATLvR9S-Gp7vQUyqerTF4dy2M01EOmA&index=2&t=13390s) .

at 4:15:00  (module 5) the presenter begins training the model on the data set, the training set shown is 50000 in the video. while for me the training set that appears when i execute the following code is only 1563.

**note**: the video is broken into modules, in each module the presenter explains a certain topic with some coding, there is a link in the description for each code in google colab.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#  LOAD AND SPLIT DATASET
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 25s 16ms/step - loss: 1.5344 - accuracy: 0.4397 - val_loss: 1.2955 - val_accuracy: 0.5370
Epoch 2/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 26s 16ms/step - loss: 1.1814 - accuracy: 0.5801 - val_loss: 1.1160 - val_accuracy: 0.6018
Epoch 3/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 1.0273 - accuracy: 0.6389 - val_loss: 0.9927 - val_accuracy: 0.6508
Epoch 4/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 26s 16ms/step - loss: 0.9338 - accuracy: 0.6710 - val_loss: 0.9715 - val_accuracy: 0.6585
Epoch 5/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 0.8640 - accuracy: 0.6968 - val_loss: 0.9137 - val_accuracy: 0.6807
Epoch 6/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 26s 17ms/step - loss: 0.8062 - accuracy: 0.7169 - val_loss: 0.8980 - val_accuracy: 0.6893
Epoch 7/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 23s 15ms/step - loss: 0.7596 - accuracy: 0.7333 - val_loss: 0.8867 - val_accuracy: 0.6946
Epoch 8/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 25s 16ms/step - loss: 0.7170 - accuracy: 0.7474 - val_loss: 0.8755 - val_accuracy: 0.6990
Epoch 9/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 25s 16ms/step - loss: 0.6837 - accuracy: 0.7566 - val_loss: 0.8597 - val_accuracy: 0.7104
Epoch 10/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 24s 16ms/step - loss: 0.6426 - accuracy: 0.7742 - val_loss: 0.8683 - val_accuracy: 0.7063
```

can someone please tell me why the code doesn't load the full data set and trains the model on it?

Comment: `training set size / batch size = 50000 / 32 = 1563` - see the duplicate thread

Comment: You are very welcome

Comment: how do get it to show training set size instead of batch number?

Comment: Not quite sure, and I think it also depends on the Keras version used.

Comment: aha, well thanks anyway.